# Correct way of building a confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, simulation, dlm

My AR(1) model is $y_t = \phi y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t \quad where \quad \epsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1) $

Here $\sigma^2 = Var(\epsilon_t) = 1$

Basically in this code I generate random values for phi and then try to recover that value using a dlm model just to see if I am using dlm correctly.

```
Method 1.
Do for i = 100 times:
    Do for j = 100 times:
        1. Randomly generate phi between 0 and 1.
        2. Generate an AR1 series with phi and sigma^2=1
        3. build a dlm model and construct a 95% CI for phi using MLE and delta method
    count[i] = number of times out of j=100 the CI contains phi.
```

vs

```
Method 2.

Do for i = 100 times:
    1. Randomly generate phi between 0 and 1.
    2. Generate an AR1 series with phi and sigma^2=1    
    Do for j = 100 times:
        3. build a dlm model and construct a 95% CI for phi using MLE and delta method

    count[i] = number of times out of j=100 the CI contains phi.
```

Which of the above 2 methods is more appropriate?

In either case the vector count should be Binomial(n=100,size=100,p=.05). Is this correct?

Comment: You use the values from the time series y$_t$ to estimate $\phi$ and the variability of the estimate determines the confidence interval for $\phi$.  Generating a uniform distribution for $\phi$ does not make sense.